# Unable to start operaBlink through selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, remotewebdriver, opera-blink

I am trying to start opera(v 36.0) using selenium 2.53.0 and Opera chromium driver _win64 (0.2.2).

When I try to run sample code, an exception occurred and browser didn't started.

Sample code:

```
            File pathToOpera = new File("E://operadriver.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.operaBlink();
            cap.setCapability("webdriver.opera.driver",pathToOpera);
            driver = new OperaDriver(cap);
```

I am getting error as

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.opera.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
at org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriverService.access$0(OperaDriverService.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(OperaDriverService.java:118)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
at org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriverService.createDefaultService(OperaDriverService.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver.<init>(OperaDriver.java:137)
```

My execution environment: win 8, 64 bit

Comment: Does it work with other version of opera driver ???

Comment: Did You set webdriver.opera.driver system property ??? Exception just said that it is not set.

Comment: @SkorpEN : I tried for 32 and 64 bit type, but not in a different version. In above added code, I set driver path in desiredCapability as well I tried by setting 'System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", pathToOpera)'. But that didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add before Your code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver","E://operadriver.exe");
System.setProperty("opera.binary","E://yourOperaPath.exe");
```

Comment: Added below code and still getting error.

System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "E://operadriver.exe");
File pathToOpera = new File("C:/Users/ajesh.ks/AppData/Local/Programs/Opera/launcher.exe");DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.operaBlink();
cap.setCapability("opera.binary",pathToOpera);
driver = new OperaDriver(cap);

I am getting below error :
Starting OperaDriver 0.2.0 (ba47709ed9e35ce26dbd960fb5d75be104290d96) on port 29660
Only local connections are allowed.
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Opera binary

Comment: It is different error. Now set up System path to opera.binary correctly.

Comment: I have uninstalled my previous installation path(AppData) and installed to default location. Also ([link]https://sny.no/2011/10/capabilities) removed desired capability set 'opera.binary'. Further to that, Opera browser started successfully, but **Console window crashes** in background.
Without close of window, further driver commands are not executed. Each time driver instantiated, console window and Browser opens and console crashed.

Comment: check with older versions(browser or driver), maybe the newest got some issues.

Comment: It's strange that, opera driver unable to pick path values though its added in system path. I have tried with Opera launcher (v.36) and driver (v.0.2.0) in win 8 platform. But still **Console Host** window opened in background and crashed.

Comment: I tried same combinations of Opera binary and driver in Win 10, 64 bit platform, that successfully started Opera browser and Console window opened without a crash.
I hope that might be a platform issue. Am concerned about binary behavior of opera, how to alter default installation path.